# Plotting the off-diagonal value of a covariance matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, covariance, covariance-matrix

This block of code outputs all 10 of my covariance matrices and plots every point in the 2x2 matrix.

```
for i in range(10):
    columns = datawithoutmean[:, i*2:i*2 + 2]
    cov = numpy.cov(columns.T)
    print(cov)
    matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(cov[:,0], cov[:,1], c = 'r', marker = '.')
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

How can I specifically output the off-diagonal value for each co variance matrix and plot it using pyplot?

For reference the first co variance matrix looks like this:

```
[[10.34020531  -0.01203439]
[-0.01203439    2.06085007]]
```

I want to plot the off-diagonal (the co variance between the two columns), so in this case it would be -0.01203439.

Edit: I found out I can get the off-diagonal like this:
Ok so If I do this, it'll output the co-variance value between the two columns:

```
for i in range(10):
    columns = datawithoutmean[:, i*2:i*2 + 2]
    cov = numpy.cov(columns.T)
    off_diagonal = cov[0][1] # covariance value
```

But how can I plot those values in a scatterplot using pyplot?

Comment: Have you tried the antidiagonal `np.diag(cov.T)`?

Comment: I just tried that and it's outputting the variance (diagonal). Even when I transpose it, it's giving me the same values (variance)

Comment: Ah, I am sorry, I meant `cov[:, ::-1]`. The transpose obviously won't work.